# Suffering from Gout problem need help?

Tags: medications, diet, joints, swelling, gout

I am 17 years old teenager, recently my joint at ankles got swollen, I thought its normal but next day I was unable to walk due pain in joint. So we wentt to Doctor using mine blood reports and in reports mine C-Reactive protein level was 61.7mg/L, Uric acid level was 7.5mg/dl and ESR was 39 mm 1st hr. So he told me that I have gout and prescribed Febutaz 80mg , Pantocid and Acyproxyum ( last two are painkillers while 1st is for reducing uric acid)  also gave diet restrictions (low purine diet) , however after 6th day my swelling was lowered I was still following diet restrictions and medication, but as soon as I head on 10th day swelling again returned ( my painkiller dosage was done before), What do I do? Cuz I have Exam in 2 months and is it enough to treat it? For your information On 8 the day I eat Ladyfinger and Raw pineapple and 7 glasses of water.

Comment: You need to see a rheumatologist. Febutaz is not the correct treatment for an initial attack of gout, and it's unlikely that gout is the correct diagnosis anyway.

Comment: Shubham, unfortunately we're not able to answer personal medical questions here. For that we need to advise, as always, that you see a doctor. Given what you wrote below, I am happy that you saw a rheumatologist and are feeling better. Welcome to the community, and we look forward to your future general health questions (unrelated to your own personal health of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have some synovial fluid drawn from the joint and examined for Crystals. If none are present the condition is not gout. 
Other possible causes of symptoms are psoriatic arthritis rheumatoid arthritis septic (infectious arthritis).
The high CRP number indicates an autoimmune condition.

Ask for steroid injection in ankle.
That may give you some relief while you try to adjust your diet to one focused on reducing inflammation.

Keep an eye out for other symptoms like skin rashes that are also caused by auto immune inflammation  causing disorders.

I had extreme ankle pain and swelling for 2 months finally got injection. Within a day ankle  was much better.
Has not recurred for 4 months.
But now I have a skin problem diagnosed as psoriasis.

My symptoms began during a high stress time in my life ( death of my sister).
Anything that helps lower stress like meditation, yoga,exercise,healthy foods will help.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks it got nearly cured, No pain no swelling! Visited rheumatologist and he prescribed some steroids worked magically. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Well apart from medications prescribed by medical physician or rheumatologist [this home remedy](http://www.upaae.com/get-rid-of-gout-pain-in-24-to-48-hours-guaranteed-using-this-natural-remedy/) is extremely effective at curing gout pain and preventing further gout attacks. May God prevent you from further gout attacks but if it reappears then must give it a try, its all natural and with no side effects.
4 Easily available Items you will need for preparing this remedy.
1, Two tablespoons of apple cider vinegar[[1]](https://upaae.com/10-proven-health-benefits-and-uses-of-apple-cider-vinegaracv/),2. One tablespoon of raw honey (Honey is for changing the strong taste of [ACV](http://www.upaae.com/10-proven-health-benefits-and-uses-of-apple-cider-vinegaracv/), if you are diabetic don't add honey).
3, Juice of One Fresh lemon[[2]](https://upaae.com/all-about-lemon-juice-and-gout-high-uric-acid-levels-research-based/).
4, A glass of water.

Use:
Mix all these items and drink the whole glass of this mixture. Prepare this drink two times a day and drink, you will notice pain reduction in less then 24 hours.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). The question should be closed as off-topic, since it's asking for personal medical advice. Although you want to help, these types of questions should not be answered on SE - the OP has to see their doctor for answers. For your future answers we also have a strict policy that all answers have to be backed up with reliable references. For more information on site policies, please take our [tour] and visit the [help] and [meta]. Thanks!